# I know C++ basics, can I find any small jobs?

Tags: c++

I learned C++ basics such as syntax, data structures, and OOP. What should I learn next to be able to find small jobs as a college student and where?

Comment: More important is to find people to hire you. Spend your time networking.

Comment: Depends on the job, and, hence, this question is primarily opinion-based. From my experience: university/college don't teach anything. You learn how to work, when you start working.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius and then it's a bit of a chicken or the egg problem

Comment: Its also good to spend the time to learn the rules of whatever group you want to join

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius sure but where can I find a job to _start working_

Comment: @stark what do you mean by group?

Comment: @Voltini "_sure but where can I find a job to start working_" I don't understand your question. By looking through your local job postings, and going to the interviews?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Would anyone hire someone who barely knows the basic of a single programming language?

Comment: @Voltini "_Would anyone hire someone who barely knows the basic of a single programming language?_" My current workplace goes by the logic of: syntax of any given programming language is easy to learn, hence obsessing over it, is pointless. Due to this, most of the interview checks the problem solving skills. Sure, you need to write some code. But you can do that in any language you are familiar with, but no advanced knowledge is required.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I forgot to mention that I'm fond of competitive programming which apparently helps improving problem soling skills, so it's not like I'm forgetting this side of the job although I should put more effort into it.

Comment: fwiw, i dont consider competitive coding as a plus at all when considering to hire someone. It could be a minus, though, because it has too little in common with real programming

Comment: @Voltini "_I forgot to mention that I'm fond of competitive programming which apparently helps improving problem soling skills_" While it may help with problem solving skills, it, typically teaches bad coding practices (short, undescriptive variable names, various useless defines, etc.), which in real work environment mostly obfuscates code, and aren't useful at all. I too liked competitive programming back in the university, but liked it only as a collection of puzzles, and, for some reason, didn't pick up all those bad practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Join open-source project. Checkout code, analyze it, learn, and once you will be more confident with your skills you can prepare your own features/fixes. Results of your pull requests will be your skills "score". The main advantage of it is seeing large-scale code, without going through job interview.
2. You can offer your skills as a freelancer. But remember that without practical knowledge your design decisions may be wrong. So don't take big contracts, because you may struggle with your own bugs.
3. Try to apply for an internship or a full/part-time job as a Junior Developer. The advantage is the same as (1) and you will get some money. But some jobs maybe not what you would expect to be, in open-source project you may choose your favorite.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is quite helpful.